# AT command set phonenumber A6

Tags: arduino, at-command, phone-number, sim-card, telecommunication

I've been playing around with the A6 Gprs chip from Ai thinker.

So I was able to send a SMS:

```
AT+CMGF=1

AT+CMGS=0031612345678
```

Is it (technical) possible to **change (spoof) the sender phone number**?
Or can I do it with other chips, like SIM900?

[AT commands A6 chip](http://www.elecrow.com/download/A6%20module%20AT%20commands.pdf)

Comment: There's no native way to do that. You get the same options like any other SIM in a phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically the phone number is not stored in the SIM card. You have IMSI inside the SIM card and this IMSI binded with your phone number and an authentication key named *Ki* in the network operator's databases.

When you want to use the operator services, your device (The chip, the handset, etc) send the SIM Card's IMSI to the network operator. Network operator search his database for that IMSI to see if that IMSI is valid or not. If it found that IMSI inside the database, then it generate a random number and encrypt it with the corresponding Ki (that is stored in the database) and returns that encrypted data to your SIM Card. As your SIM card is aware of its Ki, it can decrypt the random number and return it.

Finally if the network operator receive the correct random from the SIM card, your are authenticated to the network. after that, when you call someone or send a message, the network operator concatenate the phone number inside the database with your messages and send them to the other side.

So, no you can't!

Comment: Thank you very much, very clear awnser. So now I can stop searching for a solution..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to spoof phone numbers yourself, you need to set up a PBX solution like Asterisk, and you need service with a VOIP carrier that allows you to self assign the outbound CNUM data.  Those with a legitimate need to do this (corporate PBX admins for example) already know how to accomplish this trivial task.  Many others who wish to spoof are up to no good, so I am not going to lay out the details beyond what I have already said.  The simplest (perhaps only?) way to spoof cell phone numbers is to run your call through your PBX and back out.  I do this all the time to protect my personal cell phone number - however, the number I am sending is simply my home phone number for my VOIP line.  No dirty tricks here.  If you have a legitimate business need talk to the business sales department at your carrier.